# Transfer Data from Pointer to Local Array to Global Array Without Using For Loop

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

- I have a function which retrieves an image from a camera.
- This function has a function called GetData() which returns a pointer to the data contained by the Image object created by the camera.
- The data pointed to by GetData() is locally initialized.

Currently, I'm copying the data pointed to by GetData element by element using a for loop, but is there a way to copy the data without using a for loop? Or, better yet, avoid copying the data and just copy the pointer address and prevent the local data from being terminated.

Code:

```
void getImage(unsigned char data[]){
    // Get the image in 1d array format
    fc::Image rawImage;
    //Initializes Image object
    error = camera.RetrieveBuffer( &rawImage );

     //retrieve and return data
     unsigned char *temp = rawImage.GetData(); //returns point to data
     for(int i = 0; i < IMG_SIZE; i++){
        data[i] = temp[i];
     }
}
```

Called simply with

```
unsigned char data[size];
getImage(data);
```

Comment: Can't you use something like memcpy to copy from one buffer to another? See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: Can you construct `fc::Image` with `data` pointer?  Is there a version of `camera.RetrieveBuffer` which takes the pointer?  Can you change `getImage` to return a `fc::Image` by value.

Comment: If you want to copy an array of data, sooner or later there will be a loop. If you use `std::copy` or `memcpy` doesn't matter, internally those functions still uses loops (though probably more optimized than your simple `for` loop).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Agreed - but I doubt any optimization will make any difference to the speed of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that your data is a local object on the stack. Once your function returns, the `fc::Image` object (and the data it points to) will be destroyed. I only see three possible ways of getting that data out of the function:

- Copy the data to the destination array (like you already do, but maybe using `memcpy` or something along those lines instead of a naked for loop)
- Declare your data member to be static (so it sticks around even after the function returns), then simply set the value of the destination pointer to point to the data by `data = rawImage.GetData()`
- Possibly the best one, if you can do it: change your API! Simply accept a pointer or reference to an `fc::Image` object and pass that as the argument to `camera.RetrieveBuffer` so your data lands in the right place to begin with. Or another way would be to return your object by value, and take no arguments in that case.

The second one is kind of funky, since the data would only be valid as long as someone else doesn't call the function again, which is a terrible practice to be honest, so **I wouldn't suggest number 2**.

Also, this API is pretty bad as it is. What's the guarantee that the passed in pointer will have enough capacity? And also, how does the user know how long is the data they received? You don't return a size value or anything.

---

**EDIT:**

There's a more appropriate way of doing number 2. You can do something like this:

```
#include <unordered_map>

// Ideally this would be wrapped in a class or something. Don't use globals.
std::unordered_map<unsigned char*, fc::Image> images;

void getImage(unsigned char data*){
    // Get the image in 1d array format
    fc::Image rawImage;
    //Initializes Image object
    error = camera.RetrieveBuffer( &rawImage );

    data = rawImage.getData();
    images.insert(std::make_pair(data, move(rawImage)));
}
```

This uses an `unordered_map` to keep your local objects alive, so you can safely return pointers into them without having to worry about the lifetime of the objects.

**But in this case you will have to create a cleanup function as well:**

```
void destroyImage(unsigned char data*){
    images.erase(data);
}
```

Since the map will keep your objects around forever, you will soon start to fill up memory if you keep getting new images. If you use this method, then your users will have to call `destroyImage()` as soon as they no longer need the data to avoid leaking memory essentially. This kind of goes agains the memory management guidelines in modern C++ which encourage automatic cleanup, while this would depend on your users to call your cleanup function, which is a little unsafe, but it's still the best you can do in my opinion, since you cannot change your API.

If you can expand your API to include such a function, this is definitely a better way to extend the lifetime of your local objects, rather than marking them static.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think static may be the way to go, as cringe-worthy as it is. I can't really change the API because the function calling the getImage function needs to be independent of the fc namespace for flexibility reasons. With regards to returning the data length, I do have code to deal with that but I cut it out and modified the code I posted to make it easier to read. I'll check your answer once I check the static idea.

Comment: I included a better solution, but that requires adding another function to your API. See my edit.